# Как поставить точку останова в вызываемом из библиотеки модуле?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

В режиме отладки возникает задача поставить точку останова в модуле, расположенном в другом проекте, скажем библиотеке модулей. Сейчас я делаю так. Ставлю точку останова на вызове модуля и в режиме пошаговой отладки захожу в эту процедуру. При этом текст модуля появляется в центральной части VS, далее в нем можно ставить точку останова уже в любом месте. Иногда создаю в нужном модуле пустую процедуру и и ставлю точку останова опять же в строке вызова, для того чтобы текст модуля появился в списке открытых окон VS.

Answer (score 1):

Точку остановки можно поставить где угодно, по полному или частичному имени метода или свойства:

Debug → New Breakpoint → Break At Function

или соответствующий шорткат, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd> или <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - зависит от схемы в студии.

В появившемся диалоге введите имя метода - полное, например `ConsoleApplication10.Program.Main(string [])` или частичное - `Main`.

Если метод находится во внешней сборке, а не в текущем решении - то стоит предварительно включить отладку внешнего кода:

снять чекбокс Debug → Options → Enable Just My Code.

Answer (score -1):

> Нужно присоединить проект модуля к своему солюшену (Solution -> Add ->
>   Exesting project). И использовать его не как dll, а как проект (Add
>   references -> вкладка Projects).

Comment: Это ответ или дополнение к вопросу?